# How to add the custom icon in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

Like I have already added the custom icon to a page for example there is a page called projects and inside the projects page there is a page called tasks so I need to add the custom icon for the task page how to add the custom icon for the task page?

Like I can able to do only default icon for those but not the custom icon for the task page.

Comment: I can't quite imagine what you want. Could you post a **screenshot** that illustrates it? *Draw* that *custom icon* so that we'd see what you're talking about.

Comment: Also please be more clear - use "APEX verbage". A page in a page ? That is not possible in Apex - are you talking about a region in a page ? A list maybe ?